# Raspberry PI 2 Model B Not Detecting ds18b20 Sensor (Tested with Multiple Sensors)

Tags: gpio, python, linux, noobs, ds18b20

I just wanted to ask some advices. I have tried everything I could find,  including :

- /boot/config.txt add Line dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
- Update and Upgrade
- Updating firmware
- Buying new Sensors.
- Tried Testing GPIO4 (Pin 7)
- sudo modprobe w1-gpio && sudo modprobe w1_therm (always present)

I just cannot seem to get these sensors to pic up at all

I have rechecked my wiring and all seems Fine. was following this ([Guide](http://www.reuk.co.uk/DS18B20-Temperature-Sensor-with-Raspberry-Pi.htm))

I tried testing GPIO4 with an LED and Python.. but I cannot seem to get it to switch state to .HIGH (Possibly Faulty GPIO pin?)/(Locked by Kernel?)

Any Assistance would be appreciated.

Images of Connections

1. Connection to Raspberry Pi GPIOs

   [image: Pin Connections on Raspberry Pi]
2. Breadboard Connections and layout

[image: Bread board layout]

3. Different Angle as to see the Resistors Placement

[image: Different Angle on breadboard]

1. gpiotest Results
   [image]

Comment: Could you post a photo of your set-up and could you detail the connections you have made between the Pi and the sensor(s).

Comment: I will post Pictures now

Comment: Image of Breadboard Connections [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hMxgmxxTKwM1FCTnNNQWNSOXFqMFJRVmNYT2xUb3FJSkNz/view?usp=sharing)<br>
Image of  GPIO pins [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hMxgmxxTKwT1AzRTZ4amlsVk5TczJzV2tOQ3daNm1hOU9B/view?usp=sharing)
Image of Breadboard from the back [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1hMxgmxxTKwdUE3Q0V6MldnSDh3eXM5QjZxV29FZ3paRzBR/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you edit your post and add those photos?  It's more useful for subsequent readers.  Also could you describe the connections you have made?  It is easier to check a written description against the photos.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the photos the connections look okay.  One end of the resistor is connected to 3V3.  Is the other connected to the data output pin?

Comment: correct. the other end is connected to the data(yellow)

Comment: Okay, try to check the gpio4.  It should normally read high because of the data line pull-up.  Try my test at http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing with the wire removed from gpio4 and preferably with w1-therm and w1-gpio disabled with sudo rmmod.

Comment: Im trying to test the GPIOs with your Program... Sorry Im still quite new to linux.. its giving an Error on Line 2

gpiotest.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
gpiotest.sh: line 2: `skipped="" tested="" failed="" usage() {'

Comment: How are you starting the script?  If it's called gpiotest and made executable with chmod +x gpiotest then ./gpiotest should run the script in a terminal window.  Alternatively typing source gpiotest should also work.

Comment: I am running it with sudo ./gpiotest.

Comment: You don't need the sudo but it shouldn't do any harm.  The first five lines should be #!/bin/bash | | skipped="" | tested="" | failed="" where I have used | to indicate new line.

Comment: working.. I installed it incorrectly.. (My own fault) it returned with: Failed user gpios: None. I have Added a Picture of the Output

Comment: by Working i mean the gpiotest bash ran successfully. Still No Luck with the Sensors

Comment: So the gpio(s) are ok.  Rewire and reboot to get a clean state.  lsmod should show w1-therm and w1-gpio loaded.  Check for entries in /sys/bus/w1/devices.  The sensor should have an entry starting 28.  Could you confirm the value of the resistor? It should be around 5000 ohms.

Comment: its a 4k7 Resistor.. Just tested with Multiplier and I am Definitely getting 4700. Unfortunately no Sensor picking up yet lsmods does list w1-therm and w1-gpio

Comment: You appear to have done everything correctly.  There should be activity from w1-therm on the gpio.  Another of my tools is [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html).  It needs to run under the graphical environment on the Pi.  But it should show activity on gpio4 every minute or so.  The screen stays blank until a gpio changes state.  You can confirm piscope is working by entering the following command from the command line: **pigs w 5 0 mils 500 w 5 1** (write 0 to gpio 5, delay 500ms, write 1 to gpio5).

Comment: thank joan.. I will quickly test that out. this is very frustrating..

Comment: the piscope is running.. there a single line on almost all the gpios... most of them are green.. including the gpio4.. I will look at it for a bit.. should the graph grow

Comment: The screen only updates when there is activity.  You can use the up and down arrow keys to zoom the time-scale in and out.  There should be activity on gpio 4 at least once a minute.  I'd buzz through your wires with your meter.  Perhaps one has a break.  It must be a bad connection (unless your sensor is hot to the touch in which case it is back to front).

Comment: ok so when my circuit is on the gpio4 is grey.. when nothing is connected the gpio4 pin line is green.

Comment: Correction.. Circuit is connected and theres just a solid green line.. I did see one blimp. tough.. but im not sure what caused that..

Comment: OK I checked the circuit  trough with a Multimeter. The Values for the sensor are as Follow. 3v3 to ground: 3.3v | Data to Ground 3.28v. It also seems like gpio4 is getting 3.28v from the data of the sensor

Comment: I've just set one up.  [piscope webm video](http://abyz.co.uk/videos/DS18B20.webm) and  [piscope png](http://abyz.co.uk/images/DS18B20.png).  /boot/config.txt dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4.  I'm at a loss.  You seem to be doing everything correctly.

Comment: Possibly.  I keep mine reasonably up to date.  I'm using a B+. uname -a shows 3.18.11+ #776.  cat /etc/os-release shows I'm using Raspbian jessie.  You are probably using wheezy but that should make no difference.  One duff sensor?  Not several though.  I'd take it all apart.  Leave it a day, then try again.

Comment: agreed. I will give it a rest once more. might help.. and yes I am using weezy. (noobs) fitting.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me today, after few hours I found the answer. :)

Add this line to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
device_tree=
```

Then restart the Pi.
Hope this will fix for you too.