# DS18B20 temperature sensor not working on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: ds18b20

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and trying to hook up a DS18B20 temperature sensor to it. Current Running Raspbian Jesse which was installed onto SD card about a month ago.  Running `uname -a` returns:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.18 v7+ #846 SMP Thu Feb 25 14:22:53 GMT 2016 arm7l GNU/LINUX
```

It currently will not acknowledge that the sensor is hooked up.


I have successfully connected it to an Arduino and read temperature so I know the temperature sensor is fine and I have correctly identified the power/ground/data wires and hooked up the 4.7K resistor correctly. I have viewed the [post here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30041/raspberry-pi-2-model-b-not-detecting-ds18b20-sensor-tested-with-multiple-sensor).

I have tested my GPIO pins with the script given in the comments and they test out fine.


My current set-up method:

1. Wire to Pi as follows:

   [image]
2. Add the following to `/boot/config.txt`:

   dtoverlay=w1-gpio-pullup,gpiopin=4

Note: I have also tried it without the "-pullup" with no success.

3. Reboot
4. Type in the following commands:

   `sudo modprobe w1-gpio`

   `sudo modprobe w1-them`

   `ls /sys/bus/w1/devices`

The last command gives me the following:

```
00-08000000000  00-f00000000000  w1_bus_master1
```

After searching extensively, all of the posts that I have found are at least a year old so maybe there was a change since then?

Comment: Are you using the bare sensor or a breakout board? did you include the resistor? Give this a try https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/configure-and-test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've got your connections backwards.

> You've got the 3.3v power on pin 40, not pin 1.

[image]

Turn the Pi over and look for the square solder point. That is pin 1.
Pin 1 is the pin closest to the PWR led.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  This is a bit embarrassing....I spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: @EricB No problem! And no worries, I've done the same and worse, it happens to all of us!